# Copy contents a file present in multiple directories to one file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy multiple files with the same name in different directories into one file.

```
A:/D/D01/a small file.txt
A:/D/D02/a small file.txt
A:/D/D03/a small file.txt
A:/D/D04/a small file.txt
--------------------------
A:/D/D09/a small file.txt
```

I am trying to copy all "a small file.txt" files to another file A:/D/new.txt

I am trying this in command prompt

```
A:\D>copy D*\"a small file.txt" new.txt
```

But I am getting an error message every time:

```
**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**
```

Please note that some of the direcories do not contain the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `COPY` command can't do what you want to do. Here is one method to do it.

This uses the `FOR` command to loop through a list of file paths returned by the command `DIR A:\D\a small file.txt" /s /b`. For each file path in the list, the `TYPE` command lists the contents which are redirected to the file `new.txt` using the `>>` output redirector.

```
FOR /F "delims= usebackq" %%f IN (`DIR "A:\D\a small file.txt" /s /b`) DO TYPE %%f>>A:\D\new.txt
```